# Unity Google admobs

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

For some time now I've been struggling to place google admobs for my game. 
I have followed this tutorial from googles official site : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/games#unity

1) I have imported the googleMobileAds.unitypackage

2) I've added google-play-services_lib/ folder into Assets/Plugins/Android folder

3) I've created my ad-unit-id from admobs

4) I've added my ad-unity-id to my script

5) I've attached my script to my main camera

When I build the app to my phone nothing shows up.
What am I missing?
Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's one thing you might notice, google ads take time to show.

If you are new at admob/adsense it takes even longer. Let me remember you Google's Adsense service sell their ads so the announcers are looking for people with a lot of impressions to publish. If you are new to the service, it might take a while until something appear

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there a way to ensure admobs will be working correctly for when it does show up? if so, what can I do?

Comment: It takes a while but not too much, you can try using your app for a while, and if you don't have a script to refresh your ad let's say, every 3 or 4 games, it's nice to do that. Doing that you'll be forcing Google Adsense to search new advertising for you. Just a quick reminder. You must be connected to the internet, otherwise your banner won't appear. I don't know if there is another way to  check if there is a banner or if it's working directly on your phone.